# Safe way to push the local value into a static mut

Tags: rust

Is there safe way to push the local value `kv` into a `static mut TABLE`?

```
static mut TABLE: [KV; 100] = [KV { k: -1, v: -1 }; 100];

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct KV {
    k: i32,
    v: i32,
}

fn fun(i: usize) {
    let kv = KV { k: 0, v: 0 };
    unsafe {
        TABLE[i] = kv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing the type of `TABLE` the answer is no.

To paraphrase [the section on static in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/const-and-static.html):

> Because `TABLE` is mutable, one thread could be updating it while another is reading it, causing memory unsafety. Both accessing and mutating a `static mut` is unsafe, and so must be done in an `unsafe` block

If you know you will only ever have one thread, you could decide to live with the unsafe blocks, but if not you will need to change the type of the table to safely access it from multiple threads.

To do this safely you need mutual exclusion. The standard library provides [`std::sync::Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). To create a static reference to a `Mutex` though, you will need [the crate `lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static). With those two ingredients you can use your table like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref TABLE: Mutex<[KV; 100]> = Mutex::new([KV { k: -1, v: -1 }; 100]);
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct KV {
    k: i32,
    v: i32,
}

fn update_table(i: usize, elem: KV) {
    let mut table = TABLE.lock().unwrap();
    table[i] = elem;
}

fn read_table(i: usize) -> KV {
    let table = TABLE.lock().unwrap();
    table[i]
}

fn main() {
    update_table(5, KV { k: 23, v: 35 });

    println!("{:?}", read_table(5));
}
```

Remember to add `lazy_static` to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
lazy_static = "0.1.*"
```